# How to get Polygon Co-ordinates which is at angle X?

Tags: google-maps

Let say I have a line, which co-ordinates are (0,0) and (5,0) which is straight. Now I move the line to 45 degree. What will be co-ordinates now? 
Similar, I have to do this for triangle, polygon. I have only co-ordinates and angle. I need the new co-ordinates.

Comment: I got the new co-ordinates, by using y=mx+c where m= tan45, but what about polygon

Comment: Other than the seemingly randomly applied tags, what makes this a GIS question?

Comment: This is called Cartesian to Polar conversion: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/converting-cartesian-polar-coordinates-d_1347.html

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions.  You also have to specify the point around which you are rotating the line segment.

Comment: @whuber, Actually I have a polygon on a map. I know all the co-ordinates and I was able to find the area. But the problem is that the polygon is inclined with some angle X. I know the angle. I now need the new co-ordinates and area at angle X.

Comment: @TreyA, Thanks but it won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'inclinded'.  Is this 2-D?  Are you looking to rotate about a point?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @TreyA, Think of it is a surface. The surface is inclined with 30 degree. I have all co-ordinates when you see the surface as plane from an high level. How to get new co-ordinates?

Answer (score 2):

some mathematical formules give you what you want, the following code is python binding but you can convert it any language with changing mathematical functions.

```
newX = oldx + math.cos((math.pi/180) * angle) * distance
newY = oldy + math.sin((math.pi/180) * angle) * distance
```

i didnt understand anything from your que. about polygon, if you want polygon area you can calculate it with below code:

with tan45 you can find other perpendicular edge... AC is our distance and BC is our other perpendicular edge and

```
polygonArea = AC * BC / 2
```

you know too,

```
tan45 =  1
```

Comment: This will not give the correct co-ordinates. Actually I have a polygon on a map. I know all the co-ordinates and I was able to find the area. But the problem is that the polygon is inclined with some angle X. I know the angle. I now need the new co-ordinates and area at angle X.